# Notepad++ Document List Maximixed when Docked on the Left

Tags: notepad++

While working in Notepad++, I accidentally managed to maximize the Document List to the entire Notepad++ desktop. There is no scrollbar to find the edge of the Document List to resize it.
I can undock it and it will dock to the right or top without issue, but when docked on the left, it takes up the entire Notepad++ application windows and you cannot see any file content, tabs or anything except for the document list and its column headers.
I looked through the config and session XML files but see nothing that indicates where the docked width is saved, nor anything about the Document List.

I tried resizing the undocked Document List and even relaunched Notepad++ but the results were always the same.

Comment: Interesting issue. May be worth reporting as a bug. Have you tried just deleting the line '<ActiveTab name="Document List" />' from your config file to reset the layout, and maybe updating and trying again? Or is it reproducible every time?

Comment: I do not have an ActiveTab node in my config.xml. <br/> I do have some ActiveTabs nodes under the GUIConfig name ="DockingManager" node, but they only have attributes of cont and activeTab which only have interger values.

Answer (score 0):

I found I could drag Notepad++ to my left screen and keep widening it to the right. moving it farther and farther to the left and eventually got to where I could see the edge of the Document List panel. Then, I was able to start resizing it to a normal width and maximize Notepad++ to restore normal function!